# Run Logout method when App is in Background

Tags: android, logout

I have an android app that requires user login credentials to access certain data. What I would like to do is that when the user has decided to exit the entire APP, not an Activity, it will invoke a logout method if the period of inactivity exceeds 20 seconds. Hence, I need a running code that is able to check if the App is in the background, this app should compliment the following code done:

IdleLogout method:

```
   public void IdleLogout(){
        Log.i("RootActivity:IdleLogout()","******APP LOGGEDOUT******");
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.pref_current_user), MODE_PRIVATE);             
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.clear();     // CLEAR ALL FILEDS
        editor.commit();    // COMMIT CHANGES 
        setloginButton();   // Change logout button to login
        RootActivity.alertDialog(RootActivity.this,getCustomIntent(PropertyActivity.class)).create().show();
        //startActivity(getCustomIntent(PropertyActivity.class)); //Return page to PROPERTYACTIVITY.    
    }
```

Wll take current activity time

```
@Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        //get the current time on exit
        curDate = new Date();
        Log.i("RootActivity:onStop()","******curDate=******"+curDate);
    }
```

Will take activity time when user resumes App

```
  @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setloginButton();
        EnquiryActivity.PROPERTY = 0;
        //EDITED FOR SESSION LOGOUT
        //Get the Resume Time
        resumeDate = new Date();
        Log.i("RootActivity:onResume()","******resumeDate=******"+resumeDate);
        long diff = resumeDate.getTime() - curDate.getTime();
        long secInt = diff / 1000 % 60; //conversion of milliseconds into human readable form
        Log.i("RootActivity:onResume()","******sectInt=******"+secInt);
        if (secInt > Inactivity_Timeout){// SET EXIT SCREEN INTERVAL LOGOUT
            IdleLogout();
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to implement a **Service** that runs in background and your app is able to communicate with. In order to do so, you should start the service in your **Application.onCreate(...)** method. Then, you should create a base activity (your activities will inherit), and implement the onPause and onResume methods for firing an Intent to the service indicating that they have gone into onPause/onResume.

The intent fired inside **onPause(...)** should indicate the service to start the countdown (20 seconds or so).

The intent fired inside **onResume(...)** should indicate the service to cancel the countdown.

When your last activity goes into background, the **onPause()** method will be triggered without later triggering **onResume** (which cancels the countdown), resulting in the session being cleared if the time elapses.

If **onStop** is called you won't be able to present a dialog inside an Activity (cause it already would have been destroyed), so I encourage you to use an activity with Theme.Dialog (or some flavor of it).

You can communicate with your service using the **LocalBroadcastManager**, and don't forget to set the BroadcastReceiver programmatically in your **Service.onCreate(...)**.

Understand that code isn't always the best answer.

Hope it helps you get some more insights of the Android platform.

Regards.

Comment: Of course, my friend. It's the way I use in my apps successfully.

Comment: Do you have multiple activities? If so, each of them should extend from a custom created activity that sends a broadcast inside onPause and inside onResume. The first tells the service to start the countdown, the latter tells the service to cancel the countdown if any. Communicate using Intents, 'cause its a fast, secure and simple way of doing it.

Comment: Yes, I do have multiple activities and I would like to clarify some of my understanding from what you have written, I am genuinely confused. Are you referring that I start by implementing  a  -> public static class MyApplication extends Application which will then call on both activityResume and activityPaused??

Comment: Application object is not static. Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html or you can just start the service in your main activity. For the service http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html you must implement a custom class that handles the intents fired by the activities.

Comment: okay, will read up that, but is my understanding to what you have written correct?

Comment: Activities fire intents inside onPause/onResume that are received by a Service. Service takes the actions of logging out a user (or maybe starting a new Activity if needed). Do you understand?

Comment: I do understand the theory in regards the service, but i have no idea on how to begin writing it